# Correlations with Ratios

Tags: correlation, ratio

I've been running an analysis whereby I've been creating ratios of two variables (e.g. A/B) and then correlating them to a third variable (variable C). These correlations have proved to be quite significant and relatively strong.

However, I have just realised that one of the variables used for creating my ratios (variable B) is by itself already correlated to Variable C, though both the strength of the correlation and its significance are weaker than in the ratio correlation. I realise it was silly of me for not having checked this beforehand but my hypothesis was focused on the ratios rather than variables A and B by themselves.

Does it still make sense to continue with my original A/B ratio correlation approach? My concern is that I may have accidentally forced the ratio correlations to be strong and significant by including variable B, which was already correlated to Variable C.

Thank you!